# Как в Grub загрузить образ windows.iso

Tags: linux, windows, grub, boot, iso

Создал мультизагрузочную флешку в линукс, но пока только с другими линукс дистрибутивами. Никак не могу заставить Grub запускать образы windows. Пробовал следующим образом:

```
menuentry "Windows 10"  --class windows --class os {
insmod ntfs
insmod ntldr
loopback loop /iso/Win_Pro_10_1607_64bit_Rus_2017.ISO
root=(loop)
ntldr (loop)/bootmgr
}

menuentry "Windows 7" {
insmod ntfs
insmod ntldr
loopback loop /iso/Windows_7_64bit_Ultimate_ru.iso
root=(loop)
ntldr (loop)/bootmgr
}
```

Весь день разбираюсь с этой темой, нашёл вариант скопировать содержимое образа в корень флешки, но мне это не подходит, так как образ не один.

Comment: Если ваша цель - просто мультизагрузочная флешка, то, может, проще взять какой-нибудь Ventoy?

Comment: @andreymal, Ventoy, конечно, намного лучше и проще, но всё таки хотелось бы самому руками потыкать и понять, как это можно сделать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если `grub` не принципиален и хочется простоты работы с установочными образами, рекомендую обратить внимание на [Ventoy](https://ventoy.net/en/index.html) для того чтобы создать загрузочную флешку, необходимо всего лишь установить программу на флешку и скопировать обычным способом ISO образы на эту флешку, работает с разными системами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Компромиссное решение

Для наиболее полного ответа проделал эксперимент.
*К сожалению 32gb флешки не было под рукой, но хватило и 8gb*

C помощью `GParted` разбил ее на 3 раздела:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На второй раздел обычным способом скопировал файлы из `iso` (win10) Третий оставил пустым так как предположил если сработает со вторым то и с третьим заработает (по принципу индукции).

На первый раздел установил `grub`, у меня в системе он второй версии поэтому соответственно устанавливал ее:

1. смонтровал первый раздел

```
mkdir /mnt/USB && mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/USB
```

2. поставил:

```
grub-install --force --removable --no-floppy --target=i386-pc --boot-directory=/mnt/USB/boot /dev/sdb
```

3. скачал конфиг:

```
cd /mnt/USB/boot/grub
wget pendrivelinux.com/downloads/multibootlinux/grub.cfg
```

4. внес изменения

```
# This Menu entry brought to you courtesy of https://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-via-grub2-using-linux/

set timeout=60
set default=0

menuentry "Windows 10" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    insmod ntldr
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    ntldr ($root)/bootmgr
}

menuentry "Reboot" {
    reboot
}
menuentry "Shut Down" {
    halt
}
```

Значение для рута получил командой `search -u UUID` из под `grub`, для этого после загрузки с флешки можно нажать `c` после чего появится ожидание ввода команд `grub>` где и следует ввести комманду поиска.
Сам `UUID` глянул в `GParted`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таким образом распаковывая `iso` в разные разделы и находя их по `UUID` можно создать флешку с разными версиями `Windows`.

На заключительном этапе очень помог `kvm`, устанавливал так для `KDE`:

`sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm`

Для теста под linux достаточно ввести команду:

`sudo kvm -boot c -drive file=/dev/sdb,cache=none -m 1024`

Опция `-m 1024` отвечает за оперативку, меньше делать не стоит, лучше больше.

В финале я добрался до приветствия, пришлось подождать минут 10.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Загрузочную флешку создать не долго. Хотелось понять, как это именно в грабе устроено, но винду без кучи костылей и танцев с бубнами не завести.

Comment: @Demyan а чем дело сейчас заканчивается, меню хоть видно?

Comment: нормально загружается меню и идёт загрузка дистрибутивов линукса, но при попытке выбрать пункт с виндой, просто вылазит "диспетчер загрузки виндовс" и говорит, что "неудалось запустить загрузочную запись", но это сообщение вылезло бы, даже если не было бы самого образа. Как я понял, это из-за самой комманды, которой запускается образ.
В общем, не судьба без особых костылей запустить образ винды из граба, уже вторые сутки вожусь.

Comment: @Demyan меня смущают некоторые настройки, например root=(loop) предполагается что-то типа root=(hd0,1), но это конечно не все, что может повлиять на проблемы с  MBR, вроде бы с виндой действительно все печально возможно даже нужно бить флешку на разделы, как я понимаю универсального варианта не существует, еще есть зависимость от биоса UEFI или нет

Comment: я разные способы перепробовал, и без этого root=(loop), что на шёл на форумах. Пока вывод: мультизагрузочную флешку можно сделать с кучей дистрибутивов линукса, и только с одной виндой, ибо распаковывать её следует в корень флешки

Comment: @Demyan, обновил ответ, решения без распаковки найти не удалось, но в качестве компромиссного решения думаю сгодится))

Comment: Похоже, реально работает. Теперь хоть где-то в интернете будет рабочая инструкция. Благодарю за помощь

Comment: @Demyan, рад что получилось помочь)

Answer (score 0):

Из - под любой винды

Откусил кусочек в 5 Гб диска, распаковал образ туда, установил `Grub4Dos`.
В `Menu.lst` дописал

```
timeout=5

default 0

title Setup 10

root (hd0,1)

chainloader (hd0,1)/bootmgr
```

(это второй раздел первого диска в представлении груба)
Перезагрузился - началась и успешно прошла установка